# how to install mysqlclient python library in linux?

Tags: python, mysql, django, kali-linux

I have a Django project and I want to deploy it on a server.But I'm unable to connect mysql.
I have tried different alternatives but I can't fixed this problem.(I have kali linux operating system)

**This is the error I am receiving when installing mysqlclient:**

```
pip install mysqlclient==2.0.0                                             1 ⨯
Collecting mysqlclient==2.0.0
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 87.9/87.9 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-go97vzkz/mysqlclient_85ab5f5ba17f42dcba9e2b66191c32e1/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-go97vzkz/mysqlclient_85ab5f5ba17f42dcba9e2b66191c32e1/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-go97vzkz/mysqlclient_85ab5f5ba17f42dcba9e2b66191c32e1/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

**This is the error I am receiving when I save 'settings.py':**

```
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/kmandi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need some additional libraries installed.

Please refer to its project description: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

> ### Linux
>
> Note that this is a basic step. I can not support complete step for build for all environment. If you can see some error, you should fix it by yourself, or ask for support in some user forum. Don't file a issue on the issue tracker.

> You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

> - `$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential` # Debian / Ubuntu
> - `% sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel` # Red Hat / CentOS

> Then you can install mysqlclient via pip now:
> `$ pip install mysqlclient`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Even adding this dependencies I couldn't get `mysqlclient==2.2.0` installed on my debian 11 or 12. I finally changed version `mysqlclient==2.1.1` in `requirements.txt` and it worked :)

Comment: on debian 12, installing all these packages (note in particular: pkg-config) allows pip to install successfully mysqlclient==2.2.0: 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config

Answer (score -1):

First install python 3.6.5, then run

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

#### Assume you are activating Python 3 venv

```
brew install mysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

Step 1: Installing MySQL Client
You can install MySQL client directly through pip using the command

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that you are helping out by answering questions :) It's important for the quality of the website that these answers are readable and clear, and good formatting helps a ton with that. Please visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and try editing your answer to improve the formatting, so that it becomes even more useful!